# Apache mod_rewrite regexp

Tags: regex, linux, apache, mod-rewrite, server

Can anyone tell me the Apache mod_rewrite code for this:

```
messages/reply/361568/T2kgdHVk%7CbyBiZW0gPyAgOik
```

My try that gives 404 error:

```
  RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}"  messages\/reply\/(\d+)\/(.*)$
  RewriteRule  messages\/reply\/(\d+)\/(.*)$    /index.php?o=m&t=reply&mid=$1&det=$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use:

```bash
RewriteRule ^messages/(reply)/(\d+)/(.+)$ index.php?o=m&t=$1&mid=$2&det=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

There is not need to use redundant `RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}"` as we can match and capture REQUEST_URI segments from `RewriteRule` itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand regexp, but I think Apache is not much friendly and a bit obscure. The most precious info for me was these FLAGS you used. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Yes, perfect, the secret are the FLAGS

Comment: I am tryint to match /messages/count but only can if I use a \/? at the end. Why ^messages\/(\w+)$ even ^messages\/(count)$ do not match, only with \/ at the end?

Comment: You can use `^messages\/(\w+)/?$` with optional `/` in the end

Comment: Works without the /? I managed to succeed. Just had to put it at the top of the file, to be the first rule.